# how to intercept calls made from an iframe in angular app

Tags: angularjs, iframe, interceptor

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', function($rootScope, $q) {
  var factory;

  factory = {
    request: request
  };
  function request(config) {
    // do something on success
    console.log('request', config.url);
    return config;
  }

  return factory;
})
```

I can use this to get all calls made within my angular app. But if a call is made from an iframe within my app, how do I intercept that call?

Thanks

Comment: That depends greatly on what is going on in the iframe and where it came from. We need a lot more details.

Comment: you don't intercept it, because the iframe is a separate page.  You would need to gain access to the iframe (via javascript if it's same-origin, or post messages otherwise) and then somehow listen for ajax requests, pending on how they are being sent.

Comment: and if that iframe is on another domain you don't control.... give up...time for a new idea. Provide more details. You can write your own interceptor on top of XmlHTTPRequest

Comment: thanks for your reply! @KevinB it is in the same origin. how do I use javascript to get the call? add a listener?

Comment: It depends on how the request is being sent.

Comment: You got any success? @charlietfl In my case iframe is in another domain. But I can see the requests in my network tab. I just need to monitor some ajax calls made by that iframe? Any hope?